# for loop Octave. Merging datasets of different size

Tags: loops, for-loop, merge, octave

In newvars.xls I have the unemployment rate (unemp) and an alcohol consumption index (alc) for 19 years for each of the US states. I also have a state (2-figures FIPS code) and year index(1994-2012).

In stataset.xls I have an index for counties (full FIPS code), an index for states(same as before), and a year index(same as before). I have 19 year-indexed observations per county.

I want to match the state-year observations of unemp and alc in newvars.xls to every single county-level observation in stataset.xls. Basically it means that for every state, I have to repeat(stack vertically) the sequence of 19 observations as many times as I have counties, and do it in the correct order. Of course the amount of counties per state varies.

First of all: the dimensions of the two tables are:
newvars=950x4 and 
stataset=58000(roughly)x3
but octave gives me

```
size newvars
ans =

   1   7

size stataset
ans =

   1   8
```

Why on earth?

Secondly, I designed the following loop to do the trick:

```
newvars= xlsread('/Project/newvars.xls');

stataset=xlsread('/Project/stataset.xls')



unemp=stataset(:,1)
alc=unemp

for i=stataset(:,2) %column 2: state index
    for j=newvars(:,1) %column 1: state index
        if stataset(i,2)=newvars(j,1)
            unemp=newvars(j,3) %column 3: unemployment inde
            alc=newvars(j,4)    %column 4: alcohol cons index
        endif
    end
end
```

But I get an error:

```
warning: suggest parenthesis around assignment used as truth value
error: A(I,J,...) = X: dimensions mismatch
```

How can I fix this? Why do the dimensions of the vectors even matter in the loop since i'm comparing individual values? Is it just a syntax error or is there a logical flaw?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: "if stataset(i,2)=newvars(j,1)" is an assignment, not a comparison. What you want is "=="

Comment: Have you looked at the other outputs of `xlsread`? e.g. `[newvars_num, newvars_txt, newvars_all] = xlsread('/Project/newvars.xls')`